# Calculadora Octadecimal a decimal con coma decimal en el octal :)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, bigdecimal

estoy tratando de hacer una calculadora de bases en python, elaborando la calculadora octal a decimal se pide que este numero octal tenga una coma decimal en su numero, por ejemplo "015.2".

He intentado hacerlo de manera de no pasar enteros, si no que, por contra parte pasar un float para que me lea el punto, pero me surge un error

Este es mi codigo:

```
def octalAdecimal(numero):
    decimal = 0
    base = 1
    while(numero):
        digito = numero % 10
        numero = int(numero/10)
        decimal += digito * base
        base = base * 8
    return decimal
num2 = int(input('Numero octal: '))
print('Decimal: {}'.format(octalAdecimal(num2)))
```

¿Alguna idea de que pueda hacer?

Comment: ¿Quieres transformar 015.2 (octal) a su valor en punto flotante (con decimales)?

Comment: Si, sé que la base octal es siempre entera, pero se me pide que esta tenga una coma decimal, por ejemplo: 
Tengo el numero octal: 47.5 y con la conversión a decimal daria algo como 2501

Comment: Puedes tener decimales en cualquier base.

Answer (score 0):

El procedimiento de conversión de la parte entera es el siguiente:

- Inicializar el resultado a cero.
- Recorrer el número octal de izquierda a derecha tomando un digito cada vez.
- Multiplicar el resultado acumulado por 8.
- Sumar al resultado el digito examinado (convertir string a entero directamente).

Para la parte decimal es similar:

- Inicializar divisor en 1 / 8.
- Recorrer el número octal de izquierda a derecha tomando un digito cada vez.
- Tomar el valor decimal del digito (str -> int), multiplicarlo por el divisor y sumarlo al resultado de la primera parte.
- Dividir el divisor por 8.

#### Código

La función de conversión recibe un valor octal en formato string. El valor recibido siempre se interpreta como octal, sin importar si traea o no un cero al comienzo (como se múltiplica por cero, da lo mismo).

```
def octalAdecimal(numero):
    valor = 0
    for idx in range(len(numero)):
        if numero[idx] == '.':
            break
        valor = valor * 8 + int(numero[idx])

    fraccion = 1 / 8
    for idx in range(idx + 1, len(numero)):
        valor = valor + int(numero[idx]) * fraccion
        fraccion /= 8
    return valor
```

#### Demo

```
tests = [
    '0',
    '1',
    '01',
    '7',
    '010',
    '777',
    '0.1',
    '0.2',
    '0.7',
    '1.1',
    '10.2'
]

for test in tests:
    print(test, octalAdecimal(test))
```

produce:

```
0 0
1 1
01 1
7 7
010 8
777 511
0.1 0.125
0.2 0.25
0.7 0.875
1.1 1.125
10.2 8.25

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Ok, gracias amigo, he entendido un poco mejor sobre como funciona. Realmente el procedimiento que necesito es al contrario, pero gracias amigo!

Comment: @Danielloaiza. Tu pregunta pide convertir octal a decimal. Si era al contrario, tienes que corregir el enunciado.