# Calculadora Hexal a decimal python

Tags: python

trato de hacer una calculadora de bases en Python, en la parte de *Hexal* a decimal me está conllevando un problema a la hora de digitar las letras en la base *Hexal*, dice que el `float` no se ha podido convertir a `string`, este es mi código:

```
   def HexalaDecimal(numero): 
     Hexa=int(numero,16)
     return Hexa 
   def HexalaDecimalFrac(numero): 
     l_partes = numero.split('.')
     num_frac = l_partes[1]
     soma = 0.0 
     for cont in range(len(num_frac)): 
       num_dig = float(num_frac[cont])
       exp = -(cont+1)
       soma += num_dig *16 ** exp
     return soma
   num = float(input("Introduce un numero Hexal:\n"))
   residuo, entero = math.modf(num)
   entero = str(int(entero)) 
   print("Hexal a decimal",HexalaDecimal(entero)+HexalaDecimalFrac(str(num)))
```

¿Alguna idea de que pueda hacer?

Comment: lo he probado y funciona con números, pero la cosa es que la representación Hexadecimal es en letras, como piensas convertir una letra en numero?

Comment: Un dato: no sé llama hex ni hexal. Es `Hexadecimal`. `Hex` es una abreviatura de éste.

Comment: Por otra parte, si a lo que te refieres por decimal es a la parte del número detrás de la coma, no hay conversión definida. No es como con los enteros que por ejemplo, 16 en decimal es 10 en hexadecimal. Las computadoras solo conocen los enteros. `3,5` es la manera en que se representa un número en la memoria.

Comment: Por favor no hagas eso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución:

```
def HexaAdecimal(numero):
    valor = 0
    for idx in range(len(numero)):
        if numero[idx] == '.':
            break
        value = int(numero[idx], 16)
        valor = valor * 16 + value

    fraccion = 1 / 16
    for idx in range(idx + 1, len(numero)):
        value = int(numero[idx], 16)
        valor = valor + value * fraccion
        fraccion /= 16
    return valor
```

#### Demo

print(HexaAdecimal("FF")) => 255
    print(HexaAdecimal("FF.A")) => 255.625

**Explicación**

Es la misma que te di cuando preguntas como [pasar de octal a decimal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/474451/calculadora-octadecimal-a-decimal-con-coma-decimal-en-el-octal/474456#474456). La copio sin más:

El procedimiento de conversión de la parte entera es el siguiente:

- Inicializar el resultado a cero.
- Recorrer el número hex de izquierda a derecha tomando un digito cada vez.
- Multiplicar el resultado acumulado por 16.
- Sumar al resultado el digito examinado (convertir string a entero directamente).

Para la parte decimal es similar:

- Inicializar divisor en 1 / 16.
- Recorrer el número hexa de izquierda a derecha tomando un digito cada vez.
- Tomar el valor decimal del digito (str -> int), multiplicarlo por el divisor y sumarlo al resultado de la primera parte.
- Dividir el divisor por 16.

Este algoritmo te sirve para cualquier base; es cosa de cambiar el valor de la base (8 -> 16).

Comment: en ese caso sería bueno colocar la base como argumento y así ya puede realizar las conversiones que quiera

Comment: @Christian. Es una solución al alcance del OP.